# What's an example of an $n$-step nilpotent Lie algebra whose centre is not $g^{(n)}$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, geometric-representation-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra. $\mathfrak g^{(1)}=\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak g^{(n+1)}=[\mathfrak g,\mathfrak g^{(n)}]=\mathbb R$-span$\{[X,Y]:X\in\mathfrak g,Y\in\mathfrak g^{(n)}\}$. The center of $\mathfrak g$ is defined by $Z(\mathfrak g)=\{X\in\mathfrak g: \forall Y\in\mathfrak g\quad[X,Y]=0\}$. $\mathfrak g$ is said to be $n$-step nilpotent if $\mathfrak g^{(n)}\neq0$ and $\mathfrak g^{(n+1)}=0$. Then $\mathfrak g^{(n)}\subset Z(\mathfrak g)$, but is there an example such that $Z(\mathfrak g)\neq\mathfrak g^{(n)}$?

Comment: Take the 4-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathbf{R}\times \mathfrak{h}_3(\mathbf{R})$. It has class 2, 2-dimensional center but 1-dimensional derived subalgebra. Similarly using direct products one gets examples for arbitrary $n\ge 2$.

Comment: One of the numerous examples beyond direct products: the 6-dim Lie algebra with nonzero brackets $12=3$, $13=4$, $23=5$, $14=6$. It has class 4, $\mathfrak{g}^4$ has basis $6$, but the center has basis $5,6$.

Answer (score 5):

Any direct sum of a $n$-step nilpotent Lie algebra and a nonzero abelian Lie algebra satisfies the required property.

Acknowledgement: After posting this answer, I realized that this class of examples was already mentioned in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1188137) by Yves.

Comment: (Note: This was said in the comments.)

Comment: Excuse me Yves, I did not notice it before. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1188187), it is probably worth having this as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered (although probably also the non-direct sum [example](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1188138) @‍YCor mentions would also be good to have as an answer).  One approach would be to edit in an explicit acknowledgement of @YCor's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1188137).

Comment: Sure, I agree: I just did it.